# Is the dual of the space of semi-regular distributions complete

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory, topological-vector-spaces, smooth-functions, frechet-space

Consider $C^\infty(X)$, equipped with its Fr'echet structure, and $\mathcal D'(Y)$, equipped with the strong topology, where $X,Y$ are compact manifolds. Is the strong dual of $C^\infty(X)\hat\otimes \mathcal D'(Y)$ a **complete** topological vector space? I have search all over the book of Treves for any hints but still am failing to determine it.

This dual is the same as $B(C^\infty(X),\mathcal D'(Y))$, the space of continuous bilinear maps $C^\infty(X)\times\mathcal D'(Y)\to \mathbb C$ (equipped with the product topology). However, I do not find any content on the regularity of this space, neither for general vector spaces nor for this specific example.

Comment: It seems like the space $B(C^\infty(X),\mathcal D'(X))$ is not necessarily strongly complete and completion may contain separately continuous bilinear form $(x, \xi) \mapsto \xi(x): C^\infty(X) \times \mathcal D'(X) \to \mathbb C$ (which is hypocontinuous on bounded sets).